# Error for "func touchesBegan" In swift

Tags: xcode, swift, fatal-error

ok so I am still learning swift and I have a crash error for my game I'm working on, when I touch the screen to make the ground move, the app crashes. The error is in green and it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" The error shows up on line 27 of GameScene.swift(close to the bottom)Here is the GameScene code

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

 var movingGround: AWMovingGround!

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let movingGround = AWMovingGround (size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width,20 ))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake( 0, view.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(movingGround)

}

**ERROR HIGHLIGHTS "movingGround.start()"**
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    movingGround.start()

}

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
 }
}
```

And this is the code for the moving ground (AWMovingGround)

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class AWMovingGround: SKSpriteNode {

let NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS = 20
let COLOR_ONE = UIColor.greenColor()
let COLOR_TWO = UIColor.brownColor()

init (size: CGSize){
    super.init(texture: nil , color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width*2, size.height))
    anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5)
    for var i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS; i++ {
        var segmentColor = UIColor()
        if i % 2 == 0{
            segmentColor = COLOR_ONE
        }else{
            segmentColor = COLOR_TWO
        }
        let segment = SKSpriteNode(color: segmentColor, size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width / CGFloat(NUMBER_OF_SEGMENTS), self.size.height))
        segment.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
        segment.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*segment.size.width, 0)
        addChild(segment)


    }

}
required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
    fatalError(" init(coder:) has not been implimented")

}

 func start(){
    let moveleft = SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width/2, y: 0,          duration: 1.0)
    runAction(moveleft, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you init the movingGround?

Answer (score 2):

Right here...

You declare moving ground

```
var movingGround: AWMovingGround!
```

But then never assign to it , you instead create a locally scoped and identically named version , which is legal and valid syntax.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
...
let movingGround = AWMovingGround (size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width,20 ))
...
}
```

So what you want is ...

```
var movingGround: AWMovingGround!

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    movingGround = AWMovingGround (size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width,20 ))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake( 0, view.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(movingGround)

}
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much, i have been trying to fix this for a very long time